# If $X$ invertible is $XX^*$ PD?

Tags: matrices

I am wondering if  $X$ invertible is $XX^*$ positive definite (PD)?
I know $XX^*$ is PSD but looking for PD.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is positive definite.

Comment: @julien Thank you. Could you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: What makes a PSD matrix PD?

Comment: If $XX^*$ is invertible then it is PD. But I don't know having $X$ invertible makes $XX^*$ invertible.

Comment: Surely you know that $\det (XY)=\det X\det Y$ and $\det X^*=\overline{\det X}$. Alternatively, try to prove that $\ker X^*=\ker XX^*$.

Comment: @julien Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First for any matrix $X$, we have $XX^*$ to be positive semi-definite, since for any vector $a$, we have $$a^*XX^*a = \Vert X^*a\Vert_2^2 \geq 0$$
All we need to show now is that if $a \neq 0$, then $X^*a \neq 0$, so that we have $\Vert X^*a\Vert_2^2 > 0$.

If $\Vert X^*a\Vert_2^2 = 0$, this means that $\Vert X^*a\Vert_2 = 0$, which in-turn means that $X^*a = 0$. However, since we are given that $X$ is invertible, the only $a$ such that $X^*a = 0$ is the vector $a=0$. Hence, for any non-zero vector $a$, we have $\Vert X^*a\Vert_2^2 > 0$. Hence, $XX^*$ is positive definite.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very informative answer.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know Singular value Decomposition?

For any $X\in M_n$, there exists a unitary $U,V\in M_n$ such that
$$
X=U^*\Lambda V,
$$
where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix with nonnegative values on the diagonal.

Then,
$$
XX^*=(U^*\Lambda V)(U^*\Lambda V)^*=U^*\Lambda\Lambda^* U
$$
$XX^*$ is similar to $\Lambda\Lambda^*$ and then we only need to show $\Lambda\Lambda^*$ is positive definite, ie., all elements on the diagonal are positive. By the fact that $X$ is nonsingular, no elements are zero on the diagonal. So all the elements on the diagonal of $\Lambda\Lambda^*$ is positive.

Comment: Using an SVD for this problem is something like taking an artillery gun to kill a fly though :)